# Leaflet CRS.Simple or CRS.EPSG3857 conversion Problem

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, java, epsg, jts-topology-suite

I'm using v-leaflet (0.61) , a vaadin plugin, to visualize some layers over a map. Clicking on the map, I create a wms query to geoserver. 
The query needs some parameters and one of them is the bbox. I suppose, by default, that the bbox, returned by the map, is in CRS.Simple, a mysterious coordinate system of leaflet.

if I set EPSG3857, both on the map and the layers, it returns me something like this as bounding box :

> Bound:6.0919189453125, 45.11617660357484, 11.134643554687498,
>   46.50217348354072

if I set EPSG4326, with the same view :

> Bound:6.0919189453125, 44.81597900390625, 11.1346435546875,
>   46.80450439453125

Seems that only the latitude values have been changed.

I've tryed also to use JTSTool (jts-topology-suite) to convert from EPSG3857 to EPSG4326 and the values are :

> bbox=4.0528551003362907E-4,5.4724638981914947E-5,4.1773613184440224E-4,1.0002420488398699E-4

It sounds so strange....

Can someone help me to understand the CRS used to define the bbox ? Or any way to transform them ?

```
"
            CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
            CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:3857");
            MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCRS, targetCRS, false);
            GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(), 4326);
            com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(bbb.getSouthWestLon(),bbb.getSouthWestLat() ));
            com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point point2 = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(bbb.getNorthEastLon(),bbb.getNorthEastLat() ));
            com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point targetPoint = (com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point) JTS.transform(point, transform);
            com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point targetPoint2 = (com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point) JTS.transform(point2, transform);"
```